# Append Tether element on custom parent

Tags: javascript, tether

Is there a way how to set custom parent element on which my target element will append with Tether?

By default all tether-elements appends to `body`. I'm attaching my dropdown element to an input inside a modal and due to z-index issues I need this dropdown to be appended on the modal, not on the `body`. Does Tether have some option to do so?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm hoping to do the same thing. Need it applied somewhere within the body but not on the body.

Comment: You can easily obtain the needed result using popper.js.org, it's a positioning library similar to Tether

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to try...

First, **make sure you're using the CSS that came with Tether.** Just adding the CSS to my project has fixed overflow problems created by the element being placed right above the closing body tag.

Also, when Tether is working it will add classes to elements, which you can use for styling things. From their docs:

### Classes

**tether-element** is added to the element

**tether-target** is added to the target

**tether-enabled** is added to both elements when tether is not disabled

**tether-element-attached-[left,right,top,bottom,middle,center]** is added to both elements based on the elements attachment, if the element becomes detached (for example, if it's pinned), that class is removed. The class reflects how the element is actually attached, so if a constraint changes the attachment, that change will be reflected in the class.

**tether-target-attached-[left,right,top,bottom,middle,center]** is added to both elements based on the target's attachment. All of the characteristics are the same as for element-attached.

### Constraint-related Classes

**tether-out-of-bounds**, **tether-out-of-bounds-[side]** are added to both the element and the target when the element is placed outside of its constraint.

**tether-pinned**, **tether-pinned-[side]** are added to both the element and target when a constraint has pinned the element to the [side] of the container.